# How should I fix this fontloader?

Tags: java, fonts

So I'm trying to make a method that returns a font object - deriving it from a .ttf, but my code isn't working:

```
public Font loadFont(){
    Font font = null;
    try {
        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("vgafix.ttf"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //Handle exception
    }
    return font;
}
```

How would I fix this?

Comment: What's not working about?  Where does `vgafix.ttf` reside within context to the source file?

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: There is no exception, it's just not drawing anything. If, instead of setting the font to null, i set it to a java default font, it works.

Comment: No exception it just doesnt draw anything. if i set the font to something else it works. the file is in the same dir as the rest of the classfiles

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: All of the logic is in here: both the call as well as the above code.http://pastebin.com/fYTC4T3d

Answer (score 1):

> it's just not drawing anything. If, instead of setting the font to null, i set it to a java default font, it works

When created the default `Font` size is `1`.  Try using something like

```
Font font = loadFont().deriveFont(12f);
```

to set the desired size of the font

> the file is in the same dir as the rest of the classfiles

You may also find that using `File` to reference the font when it resides within the context of the application may mean that the file can not be found.  When loading embedded resources you should use something more like `Class#getResource` or `Class#getResourceAsStream`, depending on your needs, for example

```
font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, getClass().getResourceAsStream("/package/path/to/resource/vgafix.ttf"));
```

Comment: It doesn't show up in 1 font either - it's not even there. I tried your solution, still nothing :(

Comment: Here's the call as well

Comment: So I'm using a rather antiquated ide - assuming that the file is in the same folder as the rest of the code, what would the call look like? Sorry, but my limited knowledge of packaging is only on Eclipse.

Comment: Assuming the file is in the same directory as the class path, the path to resource will be the same as the package name for the class...